# mongodb sharding Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set

Tags: mongodb, docker, sharding, hostname

During configuring mongodb sharded cluster

mongodb shard server (192.168.88.40) like this

```
e4dfd7df86f0        mongo:4.2           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29039->27018/tcp  MongoArb
7b903389f33d        mongo:4.2           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29029->27018/tcp  Mongors2
3a0b5edf1a89        mongo:4.2           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29019->27018/tcp  Mongors1
```

mongodb config server and mongos (both in 192.168.88.17) like this

```
492ffbbd155f        mongo:4.2       "docker-entrypoint.s…"    0.0.0.0:27019->27017/tcp    Mongos1
13bab86d8d14        mongo:4.2        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29039->27019/tcp   Configsvr3
fc1a728e1643        mongo:4.2        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29029->27019/tcp   Configsvr2
ab343b26c650        mongo:4.2        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0.0.0.0:29019->27019/tcp   Configsvr1
```

when i tries to add shard `sh.addShard('node1/192.168.88.40:29019,192.168.88.40:29029')`

```
   > Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set
```

tries

1. replicaSetName `node1` is correct (checked)
2. Not a matter of "security.keyFile" (checked)
3. ping checked in mongos.
4. mongos error log is `op_msg 20007ms` so i connected directly node1 all containers like this in `mongos`.

   mongo --host 192.168.88.40:29019 -u test-p test--authenticationDatabase admin

and connected successfully.

Comment: `node1` is `replication.replSetName`, is that right? and `sharding.clusterRole` is `shardsvr`. Note I wrote shard**svr** and not shard**srv**

Comment: @Minsky yes replSetName is node1. i checked

Comment: The error seems as if the replica set were not started. Was`rs.initiate` run in one member of the replica set nodes? This initiates replica set (**rs**)

Comment: @Minsky yes initiated replica set and can connect. as i say "mongo --host 192.168.88.40:29019 -u test-p test--authenticationDatabase admin" ( that is replica set)

Comment: Strange. You can check if there is a primary using `rs.status()` or `rs.isMaster()`.

Comment: tbh there may be something wrong with the config files and sharing that would be helpful. But anyways, maybe someone else has a better idea. [And db forum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135240/mongodb-could-not-find-host-matching-read-preference-mode-primary-for-s) is probably better suited for that. (and the link)

Comment: Configuring PRIMARY + SECONDARY + ARBITER on one host is useless. If host 192.168.88.40 goes down then the cluster is not available, configuring more than just the PRIMARY does not bring anything. The same applies for the Config Server. 3 config servers on one host is pointless. If you don't need redundancy and high availability then configure just one config server. Note, even when your replica set has only one node you have to initiate the replica set.

Comment: Did you run `rs.initiate` also on the Config server?